# Most efficient way to store variadic function template arguments into a union vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, variadic-templates

I have a simple union whose constructor stores its argument in the relevant member:

```
union Data
{
    Data(int    i) : _i(i) { }
    Data(double d) : _d(d) { }
    Data(char   c) : _c(c) { }

    int    _i;
    double _d;
    char   _c;
};
```

I then have a variadic constructor which takes arguments of these types and stores them in a vector of the union using template recursion:

```
template<typename... Ts>
DataStore(Ts... ts)
{
    _data.reserve(sizeof...(ts));
    store(ts...);
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void store(T t, Ts... ts)
{
    _data.push_back(t);
    store(ts...);
}

void store()
{
    // terminal condition
}
```

This will result in a series of `vector::push_back` calls matching the number of arguments.

Is this the most efficient/fastest way to populate the union vector?

Are there any tricks (can be specific to x86-64 / Linux) I can employ to make this faster?

**Working example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

union Data
{
    Data(int    i) : _i(i) { }
    Data(double d) : _d(d) { }
    Data(char   c) : _c(c) { }

    int    _i;
    double _d;
    char   _c;
};

struct DataStore
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    DataStore(Ts... ts)
    {
        _data.reserve(sizeof...(ts));
        store(ts...);
    }

    template<typename T, typename... Ts>
    void store(T t, Ts... ts)
    {
        _data.push_back(t);
        store(ts...);
    }

    void store()
    {
        // terminal condition
    }

    std::vector<Data> _data;
};

int main()
{
    DataStore d(1, 2.3, 'c');

    std::cout << d._data.size() << '\n'
              << d._data[0]._i  << '\n'
              << d._data[1]._d  << '\n'
              << d._data[2]._c  << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: emplace_back might help? Well maybe not with the current union you have there. It would need more complex types, also *i think* you should technically std::forward the lot of 'em.

Comment: @Borgleader in my particular use case it will only ever store fundamental types, so `std::forward` wouldn't help AFAIK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initialize `_data` directly.

```
template<typename... Ts>
DataStore(Ts... ts) : _data{ts...}
{}
```

Comment: This would create a `std::initializer_list` correct? According to [this blog post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/the-cost-of-stdinitializer_list/) there is a hidden cost as initialiser_list requires copying. Quoting from the article: *a temporary array is created, wherein all the necessary elements are copy-constructed*

Comment: Braces are not  `std::initializer_list`. They never are. You're being confused with the rule where if you define an `auto` declared variable with copy initialization with braces, then the compiler will deduce the type to be `std::initializer_list` and initialize it with the list.

Comment: Oh, wait. I see what you mean. Using a brace-initializer on `std::vector` will call its `std::initializer_list` constructor... right.

Comment: @KABoissonneault yes indeed, and I guess the real question should be *can the compiler elide the temporary array created by the `initilizer_list`*?

Answer (score 4):

Since your comments indicate you're against the straightforward approach using an initializer-list, you could do this:

```
template<typename... T>
DataStore(T&&... ts)
{
  _data.reserve(sizeof...(ts));
  char dummy[] = { (_data.emplace_back(ts), '0')... }; 
}
```

That still creates an array, but it's an array of `char` which can probably be optimized away, and there's no recursion and you don't need umpteen instantiations of the `store` function template.

The initializer for each element of the array inserts one of the objects in the parameter pack into the vector (in left-to-right order). Using `emplace_back` here allows you to pass any types to the `DataStore` constructor, so that you don't create `Data` objects until they are inserted. That means there are no copies made for:

```
DataStore d{ 1, '2', 3.0 };
```

(Just an unused `char[3]` array on the stack.)

If you do decide to use an `initializer_list`, you should create it immediately, not inside the DataStore constructor:

```
DataStore(std::initializer_list<Data> list) : _data(list) { }
```

Now you can pass any number of `Data` objects to the `DataStore` constructor, so the temporary array is created outside that constructor, and then passed straight to the `vector` member. Using this, `DataStore d{ Data{1}, Data{'2'}, Data{3.0} }` will construct an array of three objects, then copy each one into the vector.

Using this constructor you can't do `DataStore{1, '2', 3.0}` because the compiler won't create an `initializer_list<Data>` from the braced-init-list of different types.

Comment: Not dead set against it, just want to understand it more so that I can make an educated decision. If, in this case, the temporary copy has no penalty, then that would be great.

Comment: The copy for your type will just be `memcpy` of 8 bytes, so not expensive. It depends how many arguments you're passing. I've edited the answer to discuss both the zero-copy solution and the `initializer_list` one in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
template<typename... Ts>
DataStore(Ts... ts)
{
    _data = {ts...};
}
```

This will make use of `emplace_back`, so you can directly pass the fundamental types you store inside union as well.

Comment: This would create a `std::initializer_list` correct? According to [this blog post](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/the-cost-of-stdinitializer_list/) there is a hidden cost as initialiser_list requires copying. Quoting from the article: *a temporary array is created, wherein all the necessary elements are copy-constructed*

Comment: I am seeing a lot more efficient assembly code generated (g++ 5.3)  for the above i.e one with the `initializer_list`. Its perhaps due to the fact that we are using trivial types here and compiler smartly optimized out the unnecessary copy.